# How to use statx syscall?

Tags: c, linux, stat

`Ubuntu 18.04`

I'm trying to use `statx` syscall introduced in the Linux Kernel `4.11`. There is a manual entry:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>           /* Definition of AT_* constants */

int statx(int dirfd, const char *pathname, int flags,
             unsigned int mask, struct statx *statxbuf);
```

So I tried to write an example by myself:

```
const char *dir_path = NULL;
const char *file_path = NULL;
//read from command line arguments
int dir_fd = open(dir_path, O_DIRECTORY);

struct statx st; //<--------------------------- compile error
statx(dir_fd, file_path, 0, &statx);
```

But it simply does not compile. The error is the `sizeof(statx)` is unknown. And actually it is not defined in `sys/stat.h`, but in `linux/stat.h` which is not included by `sys/stat.h`. But after including `linux/stat.h` the problem is there is no definition for

```
int statx(int dirfd, const char *pathname, int flags,
             unsigned int mask, struct statx *statxbuf);
```

I expected that since

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-39-generic
```

and 4.15.0-39-generic newer than 4.11 I can use it.

What's wrong?

Comment: From [the NOTES section](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statx.2.html#NOTES) of [this manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statx.2.html): "libc does not (yet) provide a wrapper for the `statx()` system call; call it using [`syscall(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html)."

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can I use `struct statx` definition defined in `linux/stat.h`? I thought headers from `linux/xxx.h` were sort of kernel private so I'm not really sure.

Comment: the `linux/xx.h` includes is a part of kernel API or ABI - it is the interface to access linux things from userspace things. For common features across systems programs can use `glibc` or `musl` or other standard C 
library and POSIX (and other standards) implementations. Currently `glibc` library does not implement `statx` call, so you have to use kernel api.

Comment: @KamilCuk Can you please expand? I thought the only way to access kernel from userspace was `syscall`s or `ioctl`s on device drivers. What do you mean by _the interface to access linux things from userspace things_?

Comment: It's an API. The kernel provides an API (structures, syscall numbers, etc.) defined in `kernel/xxx.h`. Then `glibc` is build upon that API and provides it's own API. `glibc` translates `printf("...")` in number of  `syscall(__NR_write, ...)` then `kernel/xxx.h` tells `glibc` what the number behind `__NR_write` is. You may not use `glibc` and call `syscall` yourself. As `glibc` does not provide a wrapper for `statx`, you have to call `syscall` yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently as the glibc does not provide a wrapper for the `statx` call, you have to use your kernels definitions. So either copy the `statx` structure definition from your kernel or just use it from the API the linux kernel provides. The `struct statx` is currently defined in `linux/stat.h`.

linux provides a example call to `statx` available [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/vfs/test-statx.c).

@update library support was added in glibc 2.28